# How to predict battery timeseries with sklearn.linear_model?

Tags: python, prediction, sklearn-pandas, forecast

I want to make prediction for battery timeseries as learning oportuninty, since I'm beginner and I thought this would be nice to have in work, to monitor and see expected date & time with last forecasted value to know when to exchange battery on our devices.

I have written this, while browsing and looking at various tutorials. But I keep crashing on forecasted values... they should be lower than the last value, going down in linear pattern.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

### ____ import to DataFrame ____ ###

df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_csv ('c:\_Python\Forecast\Battery_Data.csv',sep=";")
df.columns = ["Date","AKU"]
#df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

### ____ Creating model for ForeCast ____ ###

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

X = df["Date"].values.reshape(-1, 1)
Y = df["AKU"].values

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X,Y)
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

last_date = df.index[-1]

forecast_dates = [last_date + timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(0, 10000)]
print(forecast_dates) # - returns numbers but in Julian format
forecast_dates_julian = [date.to_julian_date() for date in forecast_dates]
#print(forecast_dates_julian) # - returns numbers but in Julian format
forecast_dates_julian = np.array(forecast_dates_julian).reshape(-1, 1)
#print(forecast_dates_julian) # - returns numbers but in Julian format but in array

forecast_battery_values = model.predict(forecast_dates_julian)

forecast_data = pd.DataFrame({"Date": forecast_dates, "AKU": forecast_battery_values})
forecast_data.set_index("Date", inplace=True)


### ____ Export for the forecasted data ____ ###



### ____ Plotting data to see the forecast ____ ###

plt.plot(df,
         label='Battery real',
         color='blue')
plt.plot(forecast_data,
         label='Battery forecast',
         color='red',
         ls='dotted')
plt.axvline(x=df.index[-1],
            color='green',
            ls='--',
            label='Divider')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I don't know if the julian format is making this mistake, but I don't know how to change it to normal UTC format or numbers.